# Can I pass a GROUP BY to an API call?

Tags: api, database

I'm trying to write an API call returning all contacts that are at one end of one or more active relationships of a certain type, and their names. I note that you can specify limit, offset (LIMIT) and sort (ORDER BY) options. Something similar for GROUP BY, so I don't need to do this in PHP separately after the API call, would be useful. Does it exist?

Like this, for example:

```
$ao_result = civicrm_api('Relationship', 'get', array(
  'version'    => 3,
  'sequential' => 1,
  'relationship_type_id' => 19,
  'is_active'  => TRUE,
  'options'    => array(
    'group_by' => 'contact_id_b',
  ),
  'api.Contact.getvalue' => array(
    'id'     => '$value.contact_id_b',
    'return' => 'display_name',
  ),
));
```

Comment: Or even 'group_by' => array('contact_id_b'), because you can have more than one.

Comment: Could this be implemented solely in api/v3/utils.php or would it need to be all the CRM_*_BAO_Query and other places as well?

Answer (score 3):

I think this makes sense as an addition - but note that there are 3 types of get api

1) api layer api - e.g anything that uses basic_get
2) query object api (contact, contribute etc)
3) random assorted api

## 1 is easy & in one place - 2 & 3 are ... not

BUT #1 changes substantially in 4.7 compared to 4.6 so you would need to fix at minimum in 4.7 & add unit tests and ALSO in 4.6 if you want it to work there too.

(We are open to backporting the 4.7 internals en masse to 4.6 with an self-deprecating opt-in -eg. $params['options']['4.7plusmode'] = TRUE;
- the 4.7 code also supports custom field filters (e.g on address) and lays the groundwork for more nuanced acls since it permits joins in simple api which is a blocker in 4.6)

Answer (score 3):

Years later - but GroupBy on multiple fields is now a feature of APIv4.  Check out the API Explorer for details.